# "Grieve over" VS "Grieve about"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have come across with a sentence that follows the same pattern of the coming sentence:

> The writer **grieved about** the usage of this term.

However, I have checked in dictionaries that *grieve* is expected to work with *over*. So, is the usage of *grieve* with ***about*** grammatically incorrect? And if that is not the case, are both constructions interchangeable?

Comment: Actually, *grieve for* is more common than either, but it may not be suitable for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence *makes sense* but is unusual. As Micah pointed out in the comments *grieved for* is more common in general.

I suppose it comes down to meaning:

1. *Grieved over the usage of the term* gives a sense of agony. The kind of agony where you wish something didn't happen.
2. *Grieved about the usage of the term* sounds to me more like a complaint. Similar to *complain about* in it's usage. I've never heard *Grieve about* used in a sentence but it's possible in other dialects (you didn't specify) it is used.
3. *Grieved for the usage of the term* is unusual in this context. Generally you *grieve for* someone and *grieve over* objects.